# Getting around "existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping metadata from articles on JAMA. I've used slight variations of the same code to do the same task with several other health/medical journals and have been able to get the data I needed. However, with JAMA, I've been getting this error message instead: "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

From Googling the error message, I suspect that this could be JAMA trying to prevent a denial of service attack. I don't think it's rate limiting because I haven't even been able to retrieve data from JAMA to begin with.

For reference, I've pasted my code below.

```html
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import csv 

json_data = []

jama2018 = requests.get('https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/issue/319/1')
soup1=BeautifulSoup(jama2018.text, 'lxml')

#Get each issue
for i in soup1:
    issue = [a.get('href') for a in soup1.find_all('a', {'class':re.compile('^issue-entry')})]
    readuissue = requests.get(issue)
    soup2=BeautifulSoup(readissue.text, 'lxml')

#Get each article 
    articlelinks = [a.get('href') for a in soup2.find_all('a', {'class':'article--full-text'})]
    for a in articlelinks:
        jamadict={"articletype":"NaN", "title":"NaN", "volume":"NaN", "issue":"NaN", "authors":"NaN", "url":"NaN"}
        openarticle= requests.get(a)
        soup3 = BeautifulSoup(openarticle.text, 'lxml')

        #Metadata for each article
        articletype = soup3.find("div", {"class":"meta-article-type thm-col"})
        title = soup3.find("meta", {"name":"citation_title"})
        volume = soup3.find("meta", {"name":"citation_volume"})
        issue = soup3.find("meta", {"name":"citation_issue"})
        authors=soup3.find("div", {"class":"meta-authors"})
        url = a

        if articletype is not None:
            jamadict['articletype']=articletype.text.strip()

        if title is not None:
            jamadict['title']=title['content'].strip()
        
        if volume is not None:
            jamadict['volume'] = volume['content'].strip()
        
        if issue is not None:
            jamadict['issue'] = issue['content'].strip()

        if authors is not None:
            jamadict['authors'] = authors.text.strip()
        
        if url is not None:
            jamadict['url'] = url

df=pd.DataFrame(json_data)
df.to_csv('jama_2018.csv')

print("Saved")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needs an User-Agent header

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/issue/319/1', headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Was this what you intended?

Comment: Tried adding a user-agent header (for Chrome). Unfortunately, still getting the same message: urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Comment: Did you run exactly as above?

Comment: Yes, I did (minus the naming of the variables to better fit my project, but that's not what would make the difference)

Comment: then perhaps you are being blocked. Have you made many attempts at this url?

Comment: This happened even with my first attempt. I suspect that JAMA is trying to prevent a denial of service attack. My university library is looking into the matter and trying to contact the publisher.

Comment: Not sure about that. I was able to run the above and a DoS defence would not be triggered by a single access attempt.